# Sidebar меню как сделать?

Tags: javascript

Как сделать sidebar меню так, как на [этом](http://ivankorsak.com/tvorchist) сайте?

Чтобы три подпункта меню всегда были видны, а при нажатии на большой заголовок меню показывалось полностью.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Через css предварительно скрываем все элементы, начиная с пятого `.item:nth-child(+n+5)`
Скрываем и раскрываем все элементы, начиная c четвёртого.

<sub>Видимо в *css* порядок начинается с **1**, а в *js* с **0**</sub>

```js
var list = document.querySelector('ul');

list.firstElementChild.onclick = function(e) {

  let expand = this.innerHTML == '↓ список' ? true : false;
  
  this.innerHTML = expand ? '↑ список' : '↓ список';
  expand ? list.classList.add('expand') : list.classList.remove('expand');
  
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

```css
.item {
  list-style: none;
  background: #E0E4E8;
  padding: 2px 4px 2px 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  user-select: none;
}

.item:hover { background: #F4F8FB; }
.list { display: list-item; }
#list { cursor: pointer; }

.item:nth-child(+n+5) {
  height: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  transition: 0.25s;
}

ul.expand li:nth-child(+n+5) {
  height: 18px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  transition: 0.25s;
}
```

```html
<ul style='width: 256px'>
  <li class='item'>↓ список</li>
  <li class='item'>item 1</li>
  <li class='item'>item 2</li>
  <li class='item'>item 3</li>
  <li class='item'>item 4</li>
  <li class='item'>item 5</li>
  <li class='item'>item 6</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но можно ли это реализовать в одном классе, чтобы не нужно было давать класс item hide элементам которые нужно анимировать, или как-то через javascript им присваивать класс, но главное чтоб у элементов в html было одинаковое название класса, спасибо

Comment: @InCourage, обновил

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function(){
  $(".title").click(function () {
      $(".content").toggle("slow");
    });
  });
```

```css
.content {
  display: none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="title">Title</div>
<div class="mini-content">
  <p>Пункт - 1</p>
  <p>Пункт - 2</p>
  <p>Пункт - 3</p>


<div class="content">
  <p>Пункт - 4</p>
  <p>Пункт - 5</p>
  <p>Пункт - 6</p>
  <p>Пункт - 7</p>
  <p>Пункт - 8</p>
  <p>Пункт - 9</p>
</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но можно ли это реализовать в одном классе, чтобы не нужно было давать другой класс  элементам которые нужно анимировать, или как-то через javascript им присваивать класс, но главное чтоб у элементов в html было одинаковое название класса, спасибо